# Why to use static in instance variable when we use "this" to call another construtor?

Tags: java

I have little confusion about the below code.

```
class TestConstructor1{
static int num,num1;
TestConstructor1(int n)
{
    this(num,num1);
    num=n;
    System.out.println("One argument constructor");
    System.out.println("Value are "+num+" and "+num1);
}
TestConstructor1(int l,int m)
{
    num=l;
    num1=m;
    System.out.println("Two argument constructor");
    System.out.println("Value are "+num+" and "+num1);
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    TestConstructor1 ts=new TestConstructor1(10);

}
};
```

The constructor is called the way it have to called i.e. it is calling two argument constructor first and then its own constructor but I am interested to know why we have to use static before the instance variable and why we cannot use instance variable without declaring as static.

I am waiting for your responses.Thank You...

Comment: You don't need to use the static keyword when calling a 'this()' constructor.

Comment: 7 questions... 0 accepts.  Please discover the big tick next to each answer.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, @jbrookover if we don't use static then we can't call two argument constructor in this case.

Comment: Thanks Harry and Software monkey.

Comment: @Vibhakar SInha not forget to accept answers on your questions as stated.

Comment: @Vibhakar: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Just FYI, the best way to express your thanks here is to use the upvote and accept button on the answers that were useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You are a little confused about how to chain constructors.  Do it like this instead:

```
private int num,num1; // instance values, initialized by constructors

TestConstructor1(int n)
{
    this(n,0);
    System.out.println("One argument constructor");
    System.out.println("Value are "+num+" and "+num1);
}

TestConstructor1(int n,int m)
{
    super(); // this call is implicit and does not explicitly need to be in the code

    num=n;
    num1=m;
    System.out.println("Two argument constructor");
    System.out.println("Value are "+num+" and "+num1);
}
```

Note that the first calls the second passing in the `n` argument it was given and a suitable default for the second argument.

---

As to passing instance variables to chained constructors... this is not possible because accessing an instance variable is implicitly a reference to `this` object, which is not permitted until the call to the `super` constructor is done, after which you can't invoke another constructor.

But the desire to pass an instance variable to this object's constructor is not logical... in essence you are saying "please initialize this object with itself"... at a point where this object is not yet initialized.  It's something of a chicken and egg problem.  You can't uses the object's values to initialize those values.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I want to pass the instance variable value to the two argument construtor not the formal parameters of single argument constructor.

Comment: You don't generally pass an instance variable to a constructor - it's the constructor's job to initialize the instance variables.  Did you mean a static variable?  You would not need to pass a static variable to a constructor - all instances of a class can access all static variables declared by the class.

Comment: I agree sir, then is there any other way to pass the instance variable without declaring static.

Comment: BTW: What you are doing in your question is fundamentally illogical - it just doesn't make sense.  You invoke a secondary constructor passing it static variables, which static variables the constructor then writes with the values which they, by definition, are already set to... then you overwrite one of the variables with the value of the initial constructor's argument.  And none of this is doing anything to the instance being constructed.

Comment: Sorry sir, I think you are very angry on me....anyway I just want to know how could I pass instance variable to the two argument constructor in this case....is this possible or not...

Comment: @Vibhakar: Once you declare the variable static, it is no longer an instance variable, but rather a class variable shared by all instances.  Again, what you are trying to do is illogical - you need to think harder about what it is that object construction is trying to achieve.

Comment: @Vibhakar: I am not angry with you... I am merely pointing out that what you are trying to do is not working, because it's simply illogical at a fairly fundamental level.

Answer (score 0):

when you say static , it belongs to a class and not a member variable for a specific object .
if you want each instance of TestConstructor1 to have its own copy of the num and num1 then remove static.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but then two argument constructor cannot be called as we are referencing num and num1 before supertype constructor is called.

Answer (score 0):

In the first line of every Constructor, there is always a call to either `super()` or `this()`. Instance variables are set to their defaults, after this call is complete. That's why you cannot use instance variables in calls to `super()` or `this()`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass instance members in a constructor because the instance is not initialized yet. You can only pass constants like static members which are members of the class:

```
public static final int DEFAULT_M = 42;

TestConstructor1(int n)
{
  this(n, DEFAULT_M);
}
```

Also you should not call methods except they are static or private and do not access members!

Answer (score 0):

We have to use static because once variables are declared as static they will get memory once only in their life time ,if you don't make them static it will get initialized again and again.